# unable to open the local database in android

Tags: android, database, cordova

I have service in android,from that service i started an activity.I called the method inside the activity from service.In that method,i open the database and tried to insert the values.Without using database,its working fine.But my app getting force closed when i used database

plugin(java file)-->service-->Activity(here i try to insert the data in database)

**service.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service 
{
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) 
    {
        Timer mTimer = new Timer(user);
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new mainTask(), 5000,60000);//1 hour=3600 s

    }

    private class mainTask extends TimerTask 
    { 
        public void run() 
        {
            toastHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }  


    private final Handler toastHandler = new Handler() 
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
             StorageHelper s=new StorageHelper();
             String a= s.UpdateValues(userid);
        }
    };    
}
```

**Activity.java**

```
public class StorageHelper extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    }

    public  String UpdateValues(int userid)
    {
        try {
            DBAdapter1 database=new DBAdapter1(this);
            database.open();
            long id=database.insert(71,4,"yes");
            database.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
        return "success";
    }
}
```

**Note**
when i open the database in oncreate its working,But inside the updatavalues() database cannot open to insert.

```
try {
    DBAdapter1 database=new DBAdapter1(this);
    database.open();
    long id=database.insert(71,4,"yes");
    database.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {

}
```

i got two type of force close

Error number 1

```
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.app.mobilyzer.DBAdapter1.open(DBAdapter1.java:68)
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.app.mobilyzer.StorageHelper.UpdateValues(StorageHelper.java:33)
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.app.mobilyzer.MyService$1.handleMessage(MyService.java:121)
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Error number 2

```
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.app.mobilyzer.MyService@44fc6280 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3063)
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2096)
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at com.app.mobilyzer.MyService.onStart(MyService.java:81)
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:420)
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3053)
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     ... 10 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both exception are of type **NullPointerException** , first one in database.open() method . `DBAdapter1.java` :68. see what you are doing in 68th line of DBAdapter1 class. always have a null check if you doubt the value can be null/empty

```
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:98)
07-09 15:16:27.859: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.app.mobilyzer.DBAdapter1.open(DBAdapter1.java:68)
```

second exception is in MyService.java service in line number 81.  in onstart method.

```
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 15:16:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(1237):     at com.app.mobilyzer.MyService.onStart(MyService.java:81)
```

Comment: database=DBHelper.getWritableDatabase(); this is the 68th line

Comment: okay but when i cal in oncreate method it working.but i need to cal in UpdateValues().how to solve this issue